# Dynamic array name in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to make the array in v-for dynamic? Like this:

```
<div v-for="(company, index) in arrayName">
    ....
</div>
```

Data:

```
data() {
    return {
        companies: [],
        arrayName: 'companies'
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial reaction would be to question why you're doing this!

If you're sure that this is what you want, you could use a computed property:

```
computed: {
    things() {
        return this.$data[this.arrayName];
    }
}
```

Then your template can just loop on `things`.

However, I would probably go for another approach. Based on the discussion in the comments, an approach using a filter could be:

```
data() {
    companies,
    filterActive: false
},
computed: {
    things() {
        if (this.filterActive) {
            return this.companies.filter(company => company.isActive);
        }

        return this.companies
    }
}
```

I assume that the array of companies contain some data that you can use to determine whether they are active or not.

Now all your button needs to do is toggle `filterActive` between true and false.

Comment: I am making a filter. When you load the page its should get the data from the companies array. But when I click on a button it should use a computed property with a filter called activeCompanies. So when I click the button I want it to change `company in activeCompanies`.. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I agree with the answer and think you can probably do anything you need through computed properties (for example, a computed prop could return different arrays depending on a state that is set with that button you are talking about), but if you feel ***really*** strongly about doing it directly in the template (and to answer the original question directly I suppose), you can actually use the $data prop in it, so in the template you could have `(val, index) in $data[arrayName]`

Comment: @twoam there are many ways to do what you want, e.g. using a filter on the original companies array, rather than storing two arrays. The best solution depends on where the data comes from in the first place and how often it changes.

Comment: @TomFenech The data comes from the database and is stored in the companies array. But how is it possible to filter on the original array when it is already defined in data?

Comment: @twoam I have edited my answer to provide you with an example.

Comment: @TomFenech Alright I thought you meant it like this nice! It works:) Only problem is I want to display all companies, active companies and unactive companies. I think I should add another boolean and make another check. But we are getting off topic.. anyway thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah the general point is that you don't need to make explicit copies of your data, you can compute derived properties which will automatically update when the data changes.

Answer (score 7):

It can be achieved with a computed property

Template:

```
<div v-for="(company, index) in myArray">
    ....
</div>
```

Instance:

```
computed: {
  myArray() {
    return this[this.arrayName];
  },
}
```